# How to use mysqlfrm.exe to recover a mysql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to recover a DB from a corrupted HD. So far, I was able to get the .frm files of the DB.

I'm trying to get the "CREATE statement" using mysqlfrm.exe, but when I try to lunch it, it closes itself immediately.

Before it closed, I took a print screen to see what was written in the shell.

Does anybody know what's happening?

[image]

Comment: Apparently, you must specify a list of paths or files to read.  You didn't do that when starting the program.

Comment: I'm not able to write anything in the shell, because it closes itself immediately after I open it by clicking 2 times on the mysqlfrm.exe icon.

Comment: You need to specify the path(s) or file(s) as a parameter when starting the program, e.g. `mysqlfrm.exe C:\RecoveredFiles`.  You may also need to specify other parameters such as the --server= parameter.

Comment: Open the path to `mysqlfrm.exe` in command prompt and type `mysqlfrm.exe --help` to see the available options to the tool. You are missing to give the path to mysqlfrm when double-clicking.

Comment: Thank everybody. I opened it from command prompt, I set parameters and I got the create statements